# Sane default fonts?

Tags: fonts, gtk

Is there a place where I can get a list of all fonts that are guaranteed to be present on any system with GTK?  I need a way to set a sane default font for some plots, and of course the sane default font must be present.

Edit:  If no specific fonts are guaranteed to be present, is there an easy way to just get **some** sane default scalable sans-serif font?  I don't care about the details.

Edit # 2:  If nothing can be guaranteed on GTK, can someone give me good platform-specific default scalable sans-serif fonts that are guaranteed to be present on any reasonable installation of Windows and *nix/X11?

Answer (score 4):

No fonts are guaranteed to be present on any system with GTK, since GTK is a cross-platform toolkit and doesn't install any of its own fonts.

Depending on how you are rendering your plots (Cairo?), any text should already be drawn in a default font. **EDIT**: Sounds like you are using `gdk_draw_layout()` to draw your text. This takes a `PangoLayout` argument. If you obtain that `PangoLayout` using `gtk_widget_create_pango_layout()`, then it should already have a sane default font set. You can even find out what font that is, by getting the `PangoContext` using `pango_layout_get_context()`, and then calling `pango_context_get_font_description()` on that.

If you are also using GNOME, then you can check the value of the `/desktop/gnome/interface/font-name`, `/desktop/gnome/interface/monospace-font-name`, and `/desktop/gnome/interface/document-font-name` keys with GConf.

Comment: I'm using a DrawingArea and gdk's drawable API for now.

Answer (score 2):

The default fonts you should use in GTK+ are "Sans", "Monospace" and "Serif". I don't believe that any specific fonts are guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Are these scalable fonts?  Can I assume any size I need is present?  Also, are they case-sensitive?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that Sans, Monospace, and Serif are scalable and have upper and lower case. They will just be the default fonts for a given platform. These are the correct default fonts to use in your app. If they're broken the fix would be to the platform, not the app.